# Use the system Compose database in Gtk applications

Tags: x11, locale, gtk, key-mapping, compose-key

I'm using a X server which doesn't implement the  XKB extension (it is VNC, but I don't think it matters, my vncviewer is running on Windows XP, I don't think it matters either).

I've set up a Compose aka `Multi_key` key.

By setting the `XLOCALEDIR` and `LC_???` environment variables, I'm able to point to a `Compose` file to which I've added some key combinations.

They are working in some programs (xev, emacs, kate, konqueror) and not others (firefox, OpenOffice, gnome-text-editor).

The applications who aren't working have their own set of compose combinations. They aren't taking the locale into account to choose the Compose data base. Modifying the system provided one on another machine where I've root access hasn't any effect on them.

The fact that it is working with `xev` makes me think that the basic settings are correct and it is the non working applications which aren't take them into account.  Does someone know how I may persuade them to do so without having root access?

Comment: Looks like it's Gtk applications that aren't working. Where exactly did you put your Compose database? `.XCompose` is tried first. In Gtk applications, is the Compose key not working at all, or do you get your system's default Compose mappings?

Comment: I copied the whole `/usr/share/x11/locale` directory, modified my copy, and used XLOCALEDIR to point to it.  I didn't found about ~/.XCompose, it is simpler but it doesn't change which applications works and doesn't. (Emacs built to use GTK works, but emacs tend to do things in its own way)

Comment: Those who aren't working have their own set of compose combinations. They aren't taking the locale into account to choose the Compose data base. Modifying the system provided one on another machine where I've root access hasn't any effect on them.

Comment: See also [How can I find out if the ~/.XCompose file has loaded?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59629/how-can-i-find-out-if-the-xcompose-file-has-loaded) I don't know how the two solutions (`GTK_IM_MODULE=xim` and `XMODIFIERS="@im=none"`) relate.

Comment: @Gilles, my guess is that the first is for GTK application to use X input method, the second is there to override some desktop settings trying to force every application to behave its way.